# Is it possible to remove vi?

Tags: linux, package-management, vi, uninstall

I want to remove the `vi` text editor from Linux but it does not show up as a package in aptitude. Is it possible to remove this?

I have already removed vim by running

```
sudo apt-get remove vim
```

I am using Linux Mint.

Comment: For the love of God, WHY?

Comment: I used to use `nvi` instead of `vim` for years.

Comment: @jasonwryan I need to prevent the program from being accidentally or intentionally executed

Comment: Is it really the execution of `vi` you want to prevent? Or rather the ability to look at, or change, certain files? If it is the latter, it might be preferable to attack the problem in a more straightforward way (e.g. file permissions or mount parameters).

Comment: @AnsgarEsztermann This has nothing to do with file permissions or privileges. I am trying to prevent the execution of vi, vim or any vi-like text editing application.

Comment: In that case, make sure all user-writeable devices are mounted noexec.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can test where `/usr/bin/vi` to lead

```
update-alternatives --query vi
```

Usually there is link to `/usr/bin/vim.tiny`

To find package name you can try

```
dpkg -S /usr/bin/vim.tiny
```

In my system I have received

```
vim-tiny: /usr/bin/vim.tiny
```

So there is additional package `vim-tiny`.

Comment: Apparently `ubuntu-minimal` depends on `vim-tiny` so I didn't remove the package. For now I just renamed `/usr/bin/vi` to disable the program.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 The command `sudo update-alternatives --remove-all vi` is more applicable in the case.

Comment: How does manually renaming `vi` disable it? Additionally, if you really did manually rename the binary, you're gonna have bundles of fun when things update that package.

Comment: @Costas The `update-alternatives` command worked and I renamed the binary back to its original name.

Answer (score 0):

Usually (always?) vi is simply a link to vim.  On my system (OpenSuSE), /bin/vi is just a symbolic link to /bin/vim.  So if you just remove both of those, it should be gone.  But as others have asked, why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: While common anymore, no, this is not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
alias vi='echo "vi not allowed (Ok, ok, if you are a vi fanatic: /usr/bin/vim)"'
```